# IE - IFRAMES / Data Uri

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, data-uri

I need to display content in a sandboxed view, mostly a full html document (`<html>...</html>`). I'm using a sandboxed iframe with *src datauri*.

```js
var 
  iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
  content = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>'
;
iframe.sandbox = '';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + content;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Unfortunately, that isn't supported in Internet Explorer...
Is there any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

1. Create a empty `index.html`, just for having a same origin iframe.
2. Access the iframe via javascript
3. Replace its content

```js
function ReplaceIframeContentCtrl() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('test');
  var content = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>";
  
  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ReplaceIframeContentCtrl);
```

```html
<iframe id="test" src="/index.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply creating an empty iframe and replacing it's content will do:

```
function insertIframeHtml(parent, html) {
  const jparent=$(parent).empty();
  const iframe=$('<iframe></iframe>').appendTo(jparent)[0];
  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}
```